# order by featured - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a products table with a column named "featured" (int, default 0). When I add a featured product on the first position it will add value "1" in this column, "2" for second position and so on. . 
My problem is when i do not have a product on the first or second position but only on the third or second one it will "promote" that third product on the first position.
Is there a way to fill the non-promoted positions (eg: first or second) with the products from the default select query and to show the featured product with the "featured" value of 3 on the third position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to keep track of what featured slots you have filled and which ones you need to fill. You may also have to worry if your list is not long enough for all your featured slots... So you can do something like:

```
$qh = mysql_query('SELECT featured, ... FROM products ORDER BY featured DESC');

//get the featured rows first;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qh)) {
    if($row['featured'] > 0) {
        $featured[$row['featured']] = $row;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
//values were inserted in reverse, so reorder them.
ksort($featured);

$idx = 1;
//make sure there was a next row from above while loop
if($row) {
    do {
       //print any featured rows that should appear at position $idx
        while(isset($featured[$idx])) {
            printRow($featured[$idx]);
            $idx++;
        }
        //$idx doesn't have a featured row, so print a non-featured one
        printRow($row);
        $idx++;
    } while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qh));
}

//print any remaining featured rows
foreach($featured as $key => $value) {
    if($featured >= $idx) {
         printRow($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the problem you select all the products, and your keysort will just do the same as mysql orderby and WHERE featured > 0. No need to sort this in php imo. Also i don't see how you fill the gaps with normal products?

Comment: @Erik, if I have a `WHERE featured > 0`, then I won't have any of the non-featured products. Granted, I could be more creative with the `ORDER BY` so that it's not necessary to reorder the keys (something like `ORDER BY featured = 0, featured`). I fill in the gaps in the do-while loop. The inner while prints featured guys until a gap is found, and then I print a non-featured after the while. In case it's not clear, not every index in the `$featured` array has a value in it.

Comment: Of course it'd be more complicated if multiple items have the same feature value, but there wasn't mention of that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy actually.
Just make the select query, and you also ask for featured.
In php you check the first featured number.
If that's bigger then 1 then you select the normal products instead.
A small example:

```
$resultsOther = array();
$result = executeQuery('SELECT featured, name, ~~ FROM products WHERE featured > 0 ORDER BY featured');
if($results[0]['featured'] > 1) {
    $resultsOther = // get other products with a limit on the query
}
foreach ($resultsOther as $r) {
    print_r($r);
}
foreach ($results as $r) {
    print_r($r);
}
```

Another way you can do this is:

```
// This will select max 5 items and if there are not enough featured items it also selects non featured.
$results = execute('SELECT featured, ~~ FROM products ORDER BY featured DESC LIMIT 5');
while ( $result = array_pop( $results ) ) {
    print_r($result); // verander deze door de functie om de producten te tonen.
}
```